# How to use Maven in a remote Linux server?

Tags: linux, eclipse, maven, remote-access, putty

I have an extracted file of maven in my remote. I am trying to add the environment variables using these commands:

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.1 
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin 
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

When I execute `mvn -version`, I get this particular error :

```
Error:  /home/z222189/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/mvn: Permission denied
```

How do I run my Maven commands on Putty which I am using to access my remote Linux server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user (z222189) doesn't have execute permission on maven.

You should manage with `chmod +x /path/to/exec` if you have root access (make sure you also have read access)

Comment: ok i tried but it is resulting in another error                                                              /home/z222189/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/mvn: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: `/bin/sh^M`happens when you try to execute a script that was edited under windows (not the same line feed). Did you edit some file under windows ?